# Packet Loss in Darwin Streaming Server

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I am using Darwin Streaming Server (DSS) to generate rtp streams.

The DSS interface configured on the server, however shows some Packet Loss which, to a certain extent, is also visible on the client side while playing the video stream.

I would like to know whether this loss signifies the packets lost while traveling over the network. More so, what could be the reasons for packet loss in my Live stream ?

Answer (score 0):

For calculating packet loss RTCP is used in form of SR and RR. It works on sequence number field present on each RTP packet. 
Yes loss signifies the packet lost over the network.
There can be many reasons for packet loss: due to bandwidth, connectivity, distance between client and server, network congestion... or client application itself.

alam

Answer (score 0):

When UDP (RTP/AVP) transport is used, the packet loss is inevitable due to the nature of UDP.
However, DSS also supports TCP transport and Reliable UDP transport, which could solve the packet loss problem, in the circumstances that the bandwidth from server to client is enough.